# PHP calling another PHP page for MySQL Query (returning JSON data)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to find out how a PHP page calls another PHP page, which will return JSON data.

I am working with PHP (UsersView.php) files to display my contents of a website. However, I have separated the MySQL Queries in another PHP (Get_Users.php) file.

In the Get_Users.php, I will have a MySQL statement to query the database for data. It will then encode in JSON and be echo-ed out.

In the UsersView.php, I will call the Get_Users.php in order to retrieve the Users JSON data. The data will then be used to populate a "Users Table".

The thing is, I do not know how to call the "Get_Users.php" from the "UsersView.php" in order to get the data.

**Part of UserView.php**

```
$url =  "get_user.php?id=" . $id;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($json, true);
```

I am trying to call the file which is in the same directory, but this does not seem to work.

**Whole of Get_Users.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bluesky");

// Test if connection succeeded
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " .
        "<br>Please retry your last action. Please retry your last action. " .
        "<br>If problem persist, please follow strictly to the instruction manual and restart the system.");
}

$valid = true;

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $valid = false;
    $arr=array('success'=>0,'message'=>"No User ID!");
    echo json_encode($arr);
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

if($valid == true){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $arr=array('success'=>1,'type'=>$row['type'],'user_id'=>$row['id'],'email'=>$row['email'],'name'=>$row['name'],'phone'=>$row['phone'],'notification'=>$row['notification']);
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }else{
        $arr=array('success'=>0,'message'=>"Invalid User ID!");
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: you'll need to "require_once" or "require" it

Comment: Why not create a function inside `Get_Users.php` that query the database and return the result as json? Then you could simply include the file and call the function from `UserView.php`. Another approach would be to make sure so `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your `php.ini` and then grab contents from the file using `file_get_contents('http://example.com/Get_Users.php', false, $content);`. Notice that you need to create a context to actually send the id to your script. You could also achieve this by making an ajax `GET` request.

Comment: @user629283 do you mean to make a function and include the Get_User.php, so i can call the function to query?

Comment: You could also set the `$_GET['id']` parameter before you include the script: `$_GET['id'] = 3; include_once('Get_Users.php');`

Comment: @Cyclone Can I just open the file and execute the query? By context, you mean I can only use the absolute link right?

Comment: @Cyclone But if I include_once('Get_Users.php');, the results will be echo onto the web page right?

Comment: @Jeffrey - I mean that you should read up on the documentation for `file_get_contents()` and `stream_context_create()` =)

Comment: @Jeffrey - You should be able to get the results from the included file like this: `$_GET['id'] = 3; $result = include_once('Get_Users.php');`. The variable `$result` will now hold the return value from the included file.

Comment: @Jeffrey thats a good idea as well. I was just going to recommend that but cyclone beat me to it :)

Comment: @Cyclone I tried the `$result = include_once('Get_Users.php');` method, but i received a warning
**Warning: include_once(get_user.php?id=1): failed to open stream: No error in C:\wamp\www\CZ3003_BlueSky\Logout.php on line 27**

Comment: @Jeffrey - The error speaks for itself. You should **not** include the parameter when including the file - this is wrong `include_once('Get_Users.php?id=1`);`

Comment: @Cyclone oh it worked now! but the whole json got echo-ed out onto the page

Comment: @Jeffrey - You should **not** use `echo json_encode($arr);`, you need to simply return the encoded data like this: `return json_encode($arr);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of different ways to accomplish this:

- You should be able to first set the actual `id` and then include the `Get_Users.php` file like this. Notice that you should **not** echo out the output from `Get_Users.php`, instead only return the encoded json data using `return json_encode($arr);`:

---

```
// set the id in $_GET super global
$_GET['id'] = 1;
// include the file and catch the response
$result = include_once('Get_Users.php');
```

- You can also create a function that can be called from `UserView.php`:

---

```
// Get_Users.php
<?php
  function get_user($id) {
    // connect to and query database here
    // then return the result as json
    return json_encode($arr);
  }
?>

// In UserView.php you first include the above file and call the function
include_once('Get_Users.php');
$result = get_user(1);
```

- You could also use `file_get_contents()`. Notice that you need to make sure so that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your `php.ini` file for this to work:

---

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/Get_Users.php?id=1');
```

To enable `allow_url_fopen` you need to open up your loaded configuration file and set `allow_url_fopen=1` and finally restart your webserver.

---

- You could also use curl to achieve the same result:

---

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/Get_Users.php?id=1');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

- An ajax request could also be made to get the result. This example uses jQuery:

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get({
    url: 'Get_Users.php',
    data: 'id=1',
    success: function(response) {
      // response contains your json encoded data
      // in this case you **must** use echo to transfer the data from `Get_Users.php`
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The first method worked, but the json will be printed on the screen (because of the "echo" in Get_User.php)

Comment: @Jeffrey - I added an explaination to how you solve this.

Comment: Thank you for all the possible solutions. its really helpful for me. The reason why I used "echo" is because I would want to use that same .php file for ajax. I thought i could also used it for php. seems like the only way is to use the "return" (using a function) instead. If not I will have to use an absolute path (with the files stored on a server).

Comment: regarding the ajax method, how can I use the json in php?

Comment: @Jeffrey - I'm not sure I understand the question? Like I said you need to actually echo out the response in case of an ajax request (which will send the output to the browser). A simple workaround in order to use the same function would be to simply add an second parameter `ajax=1` and check if this parameter is set in the function. If `ajax` is equal to 1 then you use echo to output the encoded data, if its not then simply use `return` to deliver the result to the caller.

Comment: i mean in the ajax, how do i pass the data to php so that the php could use the data to populate the tables?

Comment: @Jeffrey - This seems to be a different question. You should create a new one since the first one seems to be solved =)

Answer (score 1):

Change UsersView.php to like this

```
$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'];
$url =  "get_users.php?id=" . $id;
$url = $actual_link.$url;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($json, true);
```

This will work fine.

Comment: Thank you Angel. I am not sure what the $_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'] does. but this does not solve the problem. All I get was only the "localhost" from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], which makes the url to be "http://localhostgetusers.php?id=1"

Comment: $_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'] gets your alias name.